# Callback Functions between React Native Pages

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, callback

I am trying to grab a variable from one page in React Native and pass it another. I have tried to accomplish this with call back functions between the two pages.

I am importing the pages into each other: `import MapFilters from "./MapFilters.js";`

How do I get the selected variable from MapFilters into LucyChat?

Purpose:

Selected represents a mile range that I would like to use in a query to determine what range of markers to render on a map.

I have tested hardcoding a value in my query and I am seeing the correct result, but the purpose of Map Filters is to allow the user to manually change their search range.

LucyChat is displaying the map with the query for which markers to display.

Ex: var queryString = 'SELECT Id from Markers where Marker.Location <' + mapFilterRange;

LucyChat:

```
export default class LucyChat extends React.Component {

  passBackSelectedVar(selectedVar) {
    this.state = {
    mapFilterRange: selectedVar,  
    };

  }

    constructor(props) {

      MapFilters.getSelectedVar();

        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            isMapReady: false,
            latitude: null,
            longitude: null,
            error: null,
            coords:[],    
            mapFilterRange: null,
        };


    }
```

MapFilters:

```
export default class MapFilters extends React.Component {



    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          selected: '50'
        };
      }
      onValueChange(value: string) {
        this.setState({
          selected: value
        });
      }

      getSelectedVar() {
        LucyChat.passBackSelectedVar(this.state.selected);
      };
```

Comment: I would think a better approach is to have a parent where that is a state variable and simply pass that to both child components as prop as it seems they need to react on it.

Comment: My root is Index.js, so you're saying to include it as a state variable here? How would I update this state variable in index.js from MapFilters.js? And from there how would I pass it into LucyChat?

Comment: Can you add more context to your question on what you are trying to do? What is the purpose of `MapFilters` and `LucyChat`? Why do you need to pass from one component to another?

Comment: The purpose has been added above, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should reconsider your component structure and have something like this:

```
Range Selector (filters which user can change)
|-- Map Preview
|-- LucyChat ( Not sure what this component does )
```

The range selector would be the UI where user would select the range which would also be passed to the other 2 components via props. This way they would re-render based on that parameter change.